# Riesz representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

Suppose $\Lambda$ is a bounded linear function on a Hilbert space $H$, given by an inner product with a unique fixed vector $h_0 \in H$ such that $\Lambda(h) = \langle h,h_0 \rangle$.

Set $M = \ker (\Lambda) := \{h \in H : \Lambda(h)=0\}$.

In a textbook proof, one can fix $z \in M^\perp$, scale $\Lambda(z)=1$, and then find that $$\Lambda(\Lambda(h)z-h)=0,$$ which means $\Lambda(h)z-h \in M$. This means furthermore that $$\langle \Lambda(h)z-h,z \rangle=0.$$ How does one then use the orthogonality of $\Lambda(z)-h$ and $z$ to deduce that $\Lambda(h)=\langle h,\frac z{\|z\|^2}\rangle$?

Comment: If $\Lambda(\Lambda(h)z-h) = 0$, then does that not imply that $\Lambda(h)z-h \in M$ rather than $M^{\perp}$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan May I ask why it is necessary to note that $M=\Lambda^{-1}(0)$ is closed in the context of proving the theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\langle \Lambda(h)z - h,z \rangle = \Lambda(h)\langle z,z\rangle -\langle h,z\rangle$$
This follows from the linearity (sesquilinearity in case of complex spaces)

Comment: So we can "distribute" the $z$ and use linearity of $\Lambda(h)$ to obtain what you wrote. And $$\Lambda(h) \|z\|^2 - \langle h,z \rangle=0$$ gives the result upon solving for $\Lambda(h)$?

Comment: Letting $\alpha = \Lambda(h) \in \mathbb{F}, \beta = -1 \in \mathbb{F}, x_1 = z \in H, x_2 = h \in H, y = z \in H$ and the linearity $\langle \alpha x_1 + \beta x_2, y \rangle = \alpha \langle x_1, y\rangle + \beta \langle x_2,y \rangle$ is used.

Comment: Yes. Since a linear functional is after all scalar valued and nonzero here. Tackle the zero case separately.